# How to set a network interface to use DCHP on boot in CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, dhcp, network-adapter

I have a CentOS 7 machine that has 2 NICs, eth0 and eth1.
I have disabled eth0 (as I won't be needing it for my setup) by editing its config and setting:

```
ONBOOT="no"
```

---

And after I configured eth1 (my lan interface) as following it still won't request DHCP:

```
DEVICE="eth1"
ONBOOT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
IPADDR="10.0.0.5" # This is the IP assigned to this machine on the private network.
NETMASK="255.255.0.0"
IPV6INIT="no"
MTU="1450"
```

Now every time I reboot the system I have to manually use the command `dhclient eth1` to make it get DHCP address. What else can I do to solve this? I thought setting BOOTPROTO was the key!

Answer (score 1):

You should create 2 virtual interfaces for your second NIC: `eth1` itself for DHCP and `eth1:1` for your private network.

In config for `eth1` (file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`) you should use `DEVICE="eth1"`, `BOOTPROTO="dhcp"` and *no* `IPADDR` and `NETMASK`.

In config for `eth1:1` (file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:1`) you should configure static parameters for your local private network, such as `IPADDR`, `NETMASK`, `GATEWAY` and (it's important!) `DEVICE="eth1:1"` and `BOOTPROTO="static"`.

As a result, your configuration files should look something like this:

*/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:*

```
DEVICE="eth1"
ONBOOT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
IPV6INIT="no"
MTU="1450"
```

*/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:1:*

```
DEVICE="eth1:1"
ONBOOT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR="10.0.0.5" # This is the IP assigned to this machine on the private network.
NETMASK="255.255.0.0"
IPV6INIT="no"
MTU="1450"
```

In this case your system will boot up with right network configuration.

P.S.: If you don't need direct access to your private network `10.0.X.X` anymore, you can use only first config file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you already set "`BOOTPROTO=dhcp`", you dont need to give IPADDR, NETMASK and GATEWAY because it will bypass them.
And for dhcp, Use like this :

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
NAME=eth1
UUID=ACCORDING_TO_YOURS
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
```

And after saving file,
Just restart the service to cross check.

```
# systemctl restart network
```

NOTE : First, check if your network is static or dhcp.